# How to change DropBox chooser button to an Image?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I need to use an Image instead of using dropbox default chooser button. I have gone through their API docs and I couldn't find any such ways to use other elements for dropbox chooser. Can anyone provide me a solution for this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually quite easy. The documentation on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js has a section called "Triggering the Chooser with JavaScript" that shows how to do it. Here's some not-really-tested code:

```
<img id="chooser-image" src="whatever.jpg" />

<script>
    document.getElementById("chooser-image").onclick = function () {
        Dropbox.choose({
            linkType: "direct",
            success: function (files) {
                alert(files[0].link);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to get blob object from file's direct link?